# How to send image with pushnotification in windows phone app 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing Push Notifications. Now I want to send an image along with the notification. How should I do it? Please help me.

My toast notification is:

```
 "<toast launch=\"/text to receive\">" + "<visual>" +
 " <binding template=\"ToastText02\">" + "<text id=\"1\">" +
 Headertext +"</text>" + " <text id=\"2\">"+Message+"</text>" +
 " </binding>" + " </visual>" + "</toast>"
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have different templates depending on the content you want to send.
Here you have some examples of templates you can use: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.toasttemplatetype

In this page you can see the xaml code you should use with each one of those templates: http://www.getcodesamples.com/src/149C1734/36315A36

Answer (score 0):

Change the text within binding tag to `<binding template="ToastImageAndText02"><image id="1" src=""/><text id="1"></text><text id="2"></text></binding>`

Comment: My toast message is:  string PushNotificationXML1 = "<toast launch=\"/text to receive\">" + "<visual>" + " <binding template=\"ToastImageAndText02\">" + "<image id=\"1\" src=" + imageurl + "/>" + " <text id=\"1\">" + Headertext + "</text>" + " <text id=\"2\">" + Message + "</text>" + " </binding>" + " </visual>" + "</toast>";

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.toasttemplatetype read the remarks